# handle Cancel event in force:editRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components

I have overridden standard edit page with a lightning controller which will redirect to standard lightning record page or custom lightning component by different recordtypes.

The problem i am facing is when i press the standard Cancel button which appears on the modal, it just closes the modal, but it doesn't reditrect to record detail page.

Onpage load i am check the action is New or Edit. Is there any work around how to handle Cancel button click event.

JS -

```
if(myPageRef.attributes.actionName === 'edit') {
    var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
    editRecordEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": myPageRef.attributes.recordId,
        "nooverride":"1"
    });
    editRecordEvent.fire();

}
```

updated JS

```
if(myPageRef.attributes.actionName === 'edit') {
            var pageReference = {
                type: "standard__objectPage",
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: "Account",
                    actionName: "edit"
                },
                state: {
                    nooverride:'1',
                    backgroundContext:'/lightning/r/Account/0010K000028JP7SQAW/view'
                }
            };
            component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
            navService.generateUrl(pageReference)
             .then($A.getCallback(function(url) {
            }), $A.getCallback(function(error) {
            }));
        } else {

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add some screenshots? which cancel button exactly?

Comment: added screenshot.. these are standard buttons